# how to redirect to cart page by clicking go to check out button

Tags: magento2, cart

I need to redirect to cart page instead of checkout page as i click go to checkout button in cart drop-down.

Answer (score 0):

You add a custom link to the 'proceed to checkout button' in minicart.js.

```
magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

find :  'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,

replace : 'checkout': window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
```

After that need to apply all command.

Answer (score 0):

Override minicart.js in your custom theme and replace below code.

```
Override magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/minicart.js

Go to line num - 44

find 'checkout': window.checkout.checkoutUrl,

replace with 'checkout': window.checkout.shoppingCartUrl,
```